# Existence of solution to the equation $x^2+2y^2=p$ or $2p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that given a prime $p$ at least one of the following equations have a solution:

$x^2+2y^2=p$, $x^2+2y^2=2p$.

The hint is “consider the pairs $(u, v)$ in $u+av$ where $a$ satisfies $p|a^2+2$.

**Since the textbook has not reach the ring extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ nor any other theorems except for the Wilson’s theorem and Euler’s theorem, please try to use elementary method if possible.**

The problem is in section $2.1$ #$56$, in the book *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* by Ivan Niven, Herbert S. Zuckerman, Hugh L. Montgomery.

I tried to prove the existence of solution nonconstructive, just as we prove that there are irrational pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a^b$ is rational. I also tried to follow the hint but I failed to understand what the hint really says.

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614194/how-to-show-that-either-a25b2-p-or-c25d2-2p-has-integer-solutions-for?rq=1) and adapt accordingly. Or search further, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614765/how-to-show-a22b2-p-has-integer-solutions-for-all-primes-p-with-frac%E2%88%922?rq=1), which solves your question.

Comment: If I do not do anything wrong, when $p = 7$, both equations do not have integer solutions.

Comment: No integer solution when $p=13$.

Comment: I don’t quite understand because the textbook does not mention there could exist a counterexample,  but thank you for the effort to verify it.

Comment: In fact it's true for only about half of the primes $< 4000$.

Comment: You omited an important information from the question: "... suppose that $x$ is an integer such that $x^2 \equiv -2 \mod p$." (For clarity purposes, this $x$ is different from the $x$'s in the equations. The book uses $a$ and $b$ instead of $x$ and $y$.) It is probably not a good idea to rewrite the question heavily.

Comment: @VTifand Thank you for pointing it out. I’ll fix it.

Comment: @WilliamSun The $x^2 \equiv -2 \pmod p$ is not a hint. It is a given statement. Otherwise, there are counter-examples listed above.

Comment: @VTifand The textbook uses the variables $(a,b,x)$ instead of $(x,y,a)$ in my question. They are essentially equivalent.

Comment: @WilliamSun Yes, but you cannot say that it is a hint instead of a known statement. It is like saying "Prove that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x^3 > 0$. Hint: Consider $x > 0$," instead of saying "Given that $x$ is a positive real number, prove that $x^3 > 0$."

Comment: My apologies for those who spent effort on my mistyped hint. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is false. There is no solution for either equation for $p=5$.

In fact, $x^2+2y^2=p$ has a solution iff $x^2+2y^2=2p$ has a solution:

- If $x^2+2y^2=p$, then $(2y)^2+2x^2=2p$.
- If $x^2+2y^2=2p$, then $x=2z$ and $y^2+2z^2=p$.

Finally, $x^2+2y^2=p$ has a solution iff $p \equiv 1,2,3 \bmod 8$. See [OEIS/A033203](https://oeis.org/A033203).

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-$$x^2+2y^2=p\Rightarrow (y,p)=1\Rightarrow yw=1\text { for some }w\in\mathbb F_p$$
It follows $$y^2w^2x^2+2y^2=y^2(w^2x^2+2)=0\Rightarrow -2\text{ is quadratic residu modulo p }$$
Hence a necessary condition for the equation $x^2+2y^2=p$ have solution is that $-2$ be a quadratic residu modulo $p$. It is known that there are infinitely many of these primes.

I can not to prove that this is also sufficient condition.

On the other hand $x^2+2y^2=2p$ become the first equation multiplying by $2$ and again $-2$ quadratic residu modulo $p$ is a necessary condition in order there is solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the intended solution was related to the Thue's lemma (see here, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%27s_lemma).

We need this statement in the following form:

**Lemma.** Let $p$ be a prime and $a\in\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}$ (i.e. nonzero residue modulo $p$). Then, there are nonzero integers $x$ and $y$ such that $|x|,|y|<\sqrt{p}$ and $x+ay\equiv 0\pmod p$.

*Proof (sketch).* As was hinted in the book, consider all pairs $(u,v)$, where $u,v\in\{0,1,\ldots,[\sqrt{p}]\}$, and let $g(u,v)=u+av\pmod p$. Since $([\sqrt{p}]+1)^2>p$, there are two pairs $(u_1,v_1)$ and $(u_2,v_2)$ such that $g(u_1,v_1)\equiv g(u_2,v_2)\pmod p$. Finally, put $x=u_1-u_2$ and $y=v_1-v_2$

Now, as @Piquito pointed out, due to the necessary condition for the existence of solutions, $-2$ should be a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Then, apply lemma for $a\in a\in\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}$ such that $a^2\equiv -2\pmod p$. It clear that in this case for nonzero integers $x$ and $y$ we have $x^2+2y^2\equiv x^2-a^2y^2\equiv 0\pmod p$. On the other hand, $0<x^2+2y^2<p+2p=3p$ and, thus, $x^2+2y^2\in\{p,2p\}$, as desired.